# How can I determine if a color is greyscale with Sass?

Tags: sass

With Sass, is it possible to determine if a color is greyscale?

Something like:

```
is-greyscale(#ffffff); // returns true
```

I can see it's possible to convert a color to greyscale in Sass, but I'm not sure how, if at all, this could be utilised to determine whether or not a given color is greyscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's surpsiginle easy, I figured it out immediately after posting this question:

```
@function is-grayscale($color) {
  @return if(grayscale($color) == $color, true, false);
}

@debug is-grayscale(white); // returns true
@debug is-grayscale(blue); // returns false
```

Comment: May I ask you your usage of this function ?
I'm a bit curious. :)

Comment: I have a map containing various colors. For each color, I want to create a class to act as a button modifier. The class will change the background of the button. If the button is not grayscale, I always want the text color of the button to be white. If the button is grayscale, depending on the lightness of the background I either want the text to be white, or grey, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it does.
Thanks for the explanation, it's interesting !

Answer (score 1):

The logic above is correct if the color is 100% grayscale, however there are plenty of colors that are "almost" grayscale, e.g. `#DEDED9`

The function below measures the saturation level of a color, and if the results are less than 8%, it considers the color to be grayscale.

Example:

```
@debug color.saturation(#DEDED9); // returns => 7.0422535211%
@debug color.saturation(#E2E2D5); // returns => 18.3098591549%
```

Functions:

```
@function is-color-grayscale($color){
    $saturation: color.saturation($color);

    @if ($saturation < 8%) {
        @return true;
    } @else{
        @return false;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
@debug is-color-grayscale(#DEDED9); // returns => true
@debug is-color-grayscale(#E2E2D5); // returns => false
```

Comment: This is amazing! And actually also required for my use-case (I was previously manually adding a key to a map containing the color value specifying whether it should be treated as grayscale, this is much better)